# imported project Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: java, android, import, compiler-errors

I worked at school on a programm, but when I try to start it on my pc at home I get this error (I copied the project on a usb):

```
02-08 14:41:57.212    1672-1672/sia.school.sia14_15 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sia.school.sia14_15/sia.school.sia14_15.SIA_tabbedActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x7f050003
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x7f050003
        at android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray(Resources.java:450)
        at sia.homag.sia14_15.SIA_tabbedActivity.onCreate(SIA_tabbedActivity.java:51)
```

R file:

```
public final class R {
public static final class anim {
    public static final int abc_fade_in=0x7f040000;
    public static final int abc_fade_out=0x7f040001;
    public static final int abc_slide_in_bottom=0x7f040002;
    public static final int abc_slide_in_top=0x7f040003;
    public static final int abc_slide_out_bottom=0x7f040004;
    public static final int abc_slide_out_top=0x7f040005;
}
public static final class array {
    public static final int a_9083646153=0x7f050002;
    public static final int agregat_xy=0x7f050000;
    public static final int b_9083646153=0x7f050003; //yes, the names do have some meaning
}
/*...*/
```

SIA_tabbedAvtivity:

```
public class SIA_tabbedActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private String[] strArray;
private String scanResult;      // Speichert das Ergebnis des Barcodescanns
/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /*Error -> */ strArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.b_9083646153);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sia_tabbed);


    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
} /*...*/
```

It worked fine at school. I already tried to clean and rebuild the project and deleted the R file to regenerate it but nothing worked. And yes, there is a string array in a .xml with the correct name.

Comment: `there is a string array in a .xml with the correct name` Which is this `correct name`?

Comment: I just mean there is a array with the name "b_9083646153" so nobody answers "Have you checked if the array has the same name as in the SIA_tabbedActivity?"

Comment: No, I mean the xml file name.

Comment: A_9083646153.xml, but the filename shouldn't matter.

Comment: It **does**, indeed. You used an **invalid character**: Upper Case characters **aren't allowed**! Rename it `a_9083646153.xml` and the problem is fixed.

Comment: So I renamed it, cleaned the project and it still doesn't work, same error. As I said, it work fine on another pc, after I copied it on a usb and then on my pc it didn't work.

Comment: I wonder **how can it work** on the other PC. Upper casing is **not allowed** in resource file names! Try doing a Project/Clean, anyway.

Comment: Could it be that there are problems with git/bitbucket because I created a new xml, witch i don't synchronize with bitbucket, and copied the array in that. Now it works -_-. We uploded the project from the other pc on bitbucker but it didn't worked, it only uploaded the .java files. Because I copied it, it still trys to up/donwload to bitbucket thus causing the error, how can I disconnect it from bitbucket?

Comment: I guess you have to save the working project. Then zip it including ALL the needed files. Remove the project in Eclipse (?). Then unzip the zipped project and reimport it from the unzipped folder. It should be now independent from BitBucket.

Comment: Thanks, now it works (stupid bitbucket). The xml hat a language qualifier, maybe thats why it could have a capital letter.

Comment: No, it can't have it.